# Corrupted control appearance inside canvas

Tags: silverlight, canvas, view

We sometimes encounter with the corrupted appearance of our user control inside Canvas, which work as a tooltip there.
It looks like this:

[image: corrupted]

Instead of correct:
[image: correct]

The control is normaly added to canvas:

```
canvas.Children.Add(tooltip);
```

The tooltip is standard simple UserControl.

I noticed that similar problem has VisualStudio xaml designer sometimes too:
[image]

What's the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: Are you passing any values to tool tip?

Comment: It has its own view model set as DataContext, which loads data on hover.